# Laravel Middleware not working on some resource route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-middleware

I am following a tutorial for making a access level restriction:

https://gist.github.com/amochohan/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246

I was able to make it work somehow but there's something I need to get working which is not in the tutorial.

Provided I have followed the tutorial. I have setup this resource route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles' => ['Administrator']], function()
{
    Route::resource('changeschedule', 'ChangeScheduleController', ['only' => ['index'], 'except' => ['create']]);
});
```

So what I wanted is just to apply the `roles` middleware to a resource route but with specific route in that resource only let's say I want to be applied in the `index` only so I have that route above.

When I go to:

```
http://localhost/hrs/public/changeschedule
```

It works fine and the middleware `roles` is working fine. But why is that when I go to:

```
http://localhost/hrs/public/changeschedule/create
```

I am getting

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

So I have a no found route error. Why is that? But when I do

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles' => ['Administrator']], function()
{
    Route::resource('changeschedule', 'ChangeScheduleController');
});
```

Then it works fine but the middleware is applied to all:

```
index, create, update, edit, delete
```

I want it to be in index only.

My code:

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'          => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic'    => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest'         => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'roles'         => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
];
```

CheckRole.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Get the required roles from the route
        $roles = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route());
        // Check if a role is required for the route, and
        // if so, ensure that the user has that role.
        if($request->user()->hasRole($roles) || !$roles)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return response([
            'error' => [
                'code' => 'INSUFFICIENT_ROLE',
                'description' => 'You are not authorized to access this resource.'
            ]
        ], 401);
    }

    private function getRequiredRoleForRoute($route)
    {
        $actions = $route->getAction();
        return isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, create a constructor function and add the middleware from there, for example:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->middleware('roles:administrator', ['only' => ['index']]);  
}
```

Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#controller-middleware).

Update (The third parameter in the middleware::handle method can take the  argument):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    // $role will catch the administrator or whatever you pass
}
```

You may also check these [examples/tutorials](http://heera.it/tag/middleware) on my blog (about middleware).

Comment: Hi thanks. I forgot to mention that I tried it already. Doesn't work. When I do that seems the roles middleware is not working. Maybe because we need to specify the access allowed for that middleware like 'roles' => ['Administrator'] where to put that?

Comment: Still not working, I even tried, $this->middleware('roles', ['only' => ['index'], 'roles' => ['Administrator']]);  and not working as well.

Comment: The `middleware::handle` method should be able to recieve the `administrator` param.

Comment: Yeah I am confuse as well. $roles = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route()); that is null when i make a var_dump